# Accelerated Mobile Page and tables stick out from the screen

Tags: css, html-table, responsive, amp-html

My web pages in Wordpress uses a lot of `<table> </ table>`, but when AMP (Accelerated Mobile Page) is used in mobiles, the table stands out from the screen, turning into hidden content.

[image]

When I used the responsive CSS I could easily solve that with:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 479px)
.table {
     width: 100%;
}
```

but with AMP does not work, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the http://datatables.net library? It might help fix the issue.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

 $('.data-table').DataTable( {
  responsive: true,
        deferRender:    true,
        scrollY:        320,
        scroller:       true
 });
 
});
```

```css
table { background: #f2f2f2; }
table thead tr { background: #ccc; }
table thead tr th:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.4/b-html5-1.5.4/b-print-1.5.4/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

<!-- https://datatables.net/ -->

<table id="myInvoicesTable" class="data-table" data-order='[[ 1, "desc" ]]'> 
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="table-th--type">Type</th>
   <th class="table-th--date" data-type="date" data-format="YYYY/MM/DD">Created</th>
   <th class="table-th--date" data-type="date" data-format="YYYY/MM/DD">Due</th>
   <th class="table-th--total" data-type="number">Total</th>
   <th class="table-th--status" data-type="number">Status</th>
   <th class="table-th--action">Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  
  
  
  
  <!-- Invoices 
  **************************** -->
  <tr class="table-tr--status status--invoice-overdue">
   <td class="table-td--type">
    <div>
     <i class="material-icons">description</i>
     <span>Invoice</span>
     <span>#00001</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/11/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/14/2018</td>
   
   <td class="table-td--total">
    <div>
     <span class="total-usd">$5.27</span>
     <span class="total-btc">0.00100000</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--status">Paid</td>
   <td class="table-td--action">
    <a href="#" class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated button--action-viewinvoice">View</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  
  
  <tr class="table-tr--status status--invoice-due">
   <!-- Type -->
   <td class="table-td--type">
    <div>
     <i class="material-icons">description</i>
     <span>Invoice</span>
     <span>#00001</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/11/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/14/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--total">
    <div>
     <span class="total-usd">$5.27</span>
     <span class="total-btc">0.00100000</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--status">Paid</td>
   <td class="table-td--action">
    <a href="#" class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated button--action-viewinvoice">View</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-tr--status status--invoice-paid">
   <!-- Type -->
   <td class="table-td--type">
    <div>
     <i class="material-icons">description</i>
     <span>Invoice</span>
     <span>#00001</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/11/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/14/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--total">
    <div>
     <span class="total-usd">$5.27</span>
     <span class="total-btc">0.00100000</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--status">Paid</td>
   <td class="table-td--action">
    <a href="#" class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated button--action-viewinvoice">View</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  <!-- Credits 
  **************************** -->
  <tr class="table-tr--status status--prepay-paid">
   <!-- Type -->
   <td class="table-td--type">
    <div>
     <i class="material-icons mdi mdi-coin"></i>
     <span>PrePay</span>
     <span>#00004</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/11/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/14/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--total">
    <div>
     <span class="total-usd">$5.27</span>
     <span class="total-btc">0.00100000</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--status">Paid</td>
   <td class="table-td--action">
    <a href="#" class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated button--action-viewinvoice">View</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-tr--status status--prepay-canceled">
   <!-- Type -->
   <td class="table-td--type">
    <div>
     <i class="material-icons mdi mdi-coin"></i>
     <span>PrePay</span>
     <span>#00005</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/11/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--date">11/14/2018</td>
   <td class="table-td--total">
    <div>
     <span class="total-usd">$5.27</span>
     <span class="total-btc">0.00100000</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="table-td--status">Paid</td>
   <td class="table-td--action">
    <a href="#" class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated button--action-viewinvoice">View</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  
  
 </tbody>
</table>
```